# program rounding decimal to exponential which i dont want

Tags: c

I have a file which has data like this

USDINR12AUGFUT          58  `1344396605`  627906   2012-08-08 09:00:05  TRADE        55.1600         2  55179.50       839
USDINR12AUGFUT          59  `1344396605`  627910   2012-08-08 09:00:05  TRADE        55.1600

In my C code i read this data from a file through this line

```
void as(char line[300])
{
    sscanf(line,"%s %lf %lf %lf %s %s %s %lf %ld %lf %ld",symbol, &trade_no, &utc_sec,&utc_nano,date,time,trade_type,&ltp,&ltq,&vwap,&volume);
        if (!strcmp(trade_type,"BID"))
        {
        cout<<endl;
        printf("%s %lf %lf %lf %s %s %s %lf %ld %lf %ld\n",symbol,trade_no,utc_sec,utc_nano,date,time,trade_type,ltp,ltq,vwap,volume);

//      cha/i);
        }

        else if (!strcmp(trade_type,"ASK"))
        {
        cout<<endl;
        printf("%s %lf %lf %lf %s %s %s %lf %ld %lf %ld\n",symbol,trade_no,utc_sec,utc_nano,date,time,trade_type,ltp,ltq,vwap,volume);
//      char li[100] = "Only Ask.txt";
//      wr(li);
        }

        else if (!strcmp(trade_type,"TRADE"))
        {
        cout<<endl;
        printf("%s %lf %lf %lf %s %s %s %lf %ld %lf %ld\n",symbol,trade_no,utc_sec,utc_nano,date,time,trade_type,ltp,ltq,vwap,volume);


//          char li[100] = "Only Trades.txt";
//          wr(li);
        }
```

where i take that number as double utc_nano..The problem is when i write this in another file through another function ,the output i get is

USDINR12AUGFUT 58 `1.344e+009` 627906 2012-08-08 09:00:05 TRADE 55.1600 2 55179.50 839 USDINR12AUGFUT 59 `1.344e+009` 627910 2012-08-08 09:00:05 TRADE 55.1600

I dont want the highlighted number in exponential form ,i want it as it was in input file ..please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you want to use float for quite a few of those fields. Unless you're prepared to accept rounding errors in your trade number, Utc sec (seconds), utc nano (presumably nanoseconds)

In which case, you'll need to change the type of these fields to match and use a different scanf string to indicate you are reading (possibly long or long long) integers.

Also, you appear to be using global variables for all this, which isn't a good idea.

Comment: ya i tried using long and it workd..initialy 'long' wasnt working

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you have an unusual printf implementation. It's supposed to work [like this](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/printf/), but apparently it's not.

`%f` should be the right thing for float or double types. You should only get exponents with `%g` or `%e`. Incidentally, `%lf` should be the same as `%f`.

You could try adding precision modifiers:

```
printf("%100.20f", utc_sec);
```

That example should give a minimum field width of 100 characters, and a maximum precision of 20 digits. Those figures are totally bonkers, of course, but maybe you'll find a trick that works.

If you don't have sub-second accuracy though, there's really no need for floating point types; integers will give greater range, and, if you don't plan to do math on it, a string will give better range still.